# Can you change the data type of a customized defect field in Quality Center after it has been created?

Tags: hp-quality-center

We are using HP Quality Center and have created several custom defect fields.  When they were initially created many of the fields to alpha numeric and now want them to be purely numeric.

Is it possible to change the data type of these fields after they have been created and populated?  We can clear the values in these fields if needed to do this conversion if it's possible.

Anyone know a process to update these fields from within QC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
You should transform values in these fields to correct format, or clear them before changing type. 
If you don't values will be truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do do you know where I go to do this?  Im taking this project over and have not done any customizations in QC yet.  is it through the Tools -> Customize -> Workflow menu?

Comment: You can change field type directly in QC customization, which will warn you of potential data loss, which from what I understand is OK in this case.

Comment: Or you can manually clear field content before field type change, either by directly clearing data in project schema in db. Or if you don't have alot of records you can do the same in ui by selecting all records and choosing updates all (I think) in edit menu.